# How to "standardize" a dataset that has a variable length?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm not sure if I'm wording my question correctly, but here's the gist:
The data set, SVC 2004, I am working with has x files, each with y 7-tuples, hence the shape of the dataset becomes (x, y, 7). I have normalized the data and am inserting it into a 1D CNN for feature extraction and an RNN as the classifier. But here is the problem: **y is never the same for each file**. This causes a problem when creating the Sequential model as it needs a constant shape. Here is some of my code:

```
//DataPreprocessing
def load_dataset_normalized(path):
file_names = os.listdir(path)

num_of_persons = len(file_names)

initial_starting_point = np.zeros(np.shape([7]))

highest_num_of_points = find_largest_num_of_points(path)

x_dataset = []
y_dataset = []

current_file = 0

for infile in file_names:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(path, infile)
    file = open(full_file_name, "r")
    file_lines = file.readlines()

    num_of_points = int(file_lines[0])

    x = []
    y = []
    time_stamp = []
    button_status = []
    azimuth_angles = []
    altitude = []
    pressure = []

    for idx, line in enumerate(file_lines[1:]):
        idx+=1
        nums = line.split(' ')

        if idx == 1:
            nums[2] = 0
            initial_starting_point = nums

            x.append(float(nums[0]))
            y.append(float(nums[1]))
            time_stamp.append(0.0)
            button_status.append(float(nums[3]))
            azimuth_angles.append(float(nums[4]))
            altitude.append(float(nums[5]))
            pressure.append(float(nums[6]))

        else:
            x.append(float(nums[0]))
            y.append(float(nums[1]))
            time_stamp.append(10)
            button_status.append(float(nums[3]))
            azimuth_angles.append(float(nums[4]))
            altitude.append(float(nums[5]))
            pressure.append(float(nums[6]))

    max_x = max(x)
    max_y = max(y)
    max_azimuth_angle = max(azimuth_angles)
    max_altitude = max(altitude)
    max_pressure = max(pressure)

    min_x = min(x)
    min_y = min(y)
    min_azimuth_angle = min(azimuth_angles)
    min_altitude = min(altitude)
    min_pressure = min(pressure)

    #Alignment normalization:
    for i in range(num_of_points):
        x[i] -= float(initial_starting_point[0])
        y[i] -= float(initial_starting_point[1])
        azimuth_angles[i] -= float(initial_starting_point[4])
        altitude[i] -= float(initial_starting_point[5])
        pressure[i] -= float(initial_starting_point[6])

    #Size normalization
    for i in range(num_of_points):
        x[i] = ((x[i] - max_x) / (min_x - max_x))
        y[i] = ((y[i] - max_y) / (min_y - max_y))
        azimuth_angles[i] = ((azimuth_angles[i] - max_azimuth_angle) / (min_azimuth_angle - max_azimuth_angle))
        altitude[i] = ((altitude[i] - max_altitude) / (min_altitude - max_altitude))
        pressure[i] = ((pressure[i] - max_pressure) / (min_pressure - max_pressure))

    #data points to dataset
    x_line = []
    for i in range (num_of_points):
        x_line.append(([x[i], y[i], time_stamp[i], button_status[i], azimuth_angles[i], altitude[i], pressure[i]]))
        if (num_of_points < 713) and (i == num_of_points-1):
           for idx in range(713 - num_of_points):
               x_line.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

        if i == num_of_points-1:
            x_dataset.append(x_line)

    current_file += 1

    infile_without_extension = infile.replace('.TXT','')
    index_of_s = infile_without_extension.find("S")
    index_of_num = index_of_s + 1
    sig_ID = int(infile_without_extension[index_of_num:])
    if sig_ID < 21:
        y_dataset.append([1,0])
    else:
        y_dataset.append([0,1])

x_dataset = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in x_dataset])
y_dataset = np.asarray(y_dataset)
return x_dataset, y_dataset, highest_num_of_points

    //Class that creates my model (creation of model works perfectly)
    class crnn_model:
    def build_model(self, input_shape_num, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', input_shape = (713, 7)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
    model.add(LSTM(2))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    print(model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, verbose=0))

    yhat = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)
    print(yhat)
```

I have thought of using the file with the most number of 7-tuples as the shape, as I have hardcoded, for now, with the above code (713). Would this be a good alternative? If not, how do I go about "standardizing" or "normalizing" the number of points (y) for the input shape of the CNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are referring to variable length sequences which you can achieve by letting the `input_shape=(None, 7)`. This says that each batch the `y` could vary *but not within a batch*. So we solve this problem by:

- Implementing a [Sequence](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) that takes the data and chops into batches. For each batch it returns `(batch_size, y_max_within_batch, 7)` by **padding** using [pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/).
- Setting the `input_shape=(None, 7)` such that at runtime your model can feed on different length inputs. This says I'll however many 7-tuples at each batch.
- Optionally using a [Masking Layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/) to mask out the padded sequences so your model doesn't use the padding as features and only predicts on the correctly length of sample. You can also predict on padding which will allow predictions to take into the length of the sequence easier.

Those are mostly the tools / layers you need to handle varying length sequences in Keras. How you use them and effects of padding etc depend on the task you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, where exactly should the pad_sequences go? In the data preprocessing or where the model is built?

Comment: Inside Sequence object, where you create the batches.

Comment: I have not created any batches. I have added the code to my preprocessing, and there seems to be no problem so far. I'm currently running a test of 1000 epoch, but the accuracy from the first epoch to the current one, 200, has never changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, people tend to handpick an arbitrary length. Any shorter sequences get padded (generally with zeroes), and any longer sequences get truncated.

What length you pick depends on the dataset; generally I make a histogram of the lengths, and then eyeball a number that keeps most of the data without too much unnecessary padding. Often that's right around the 90th-95th percentile. However, if the longest length isn't too much longer than the average length (e.g. it's less than a factor of two), it wouldn't be unreasonable to make that the number.

---

Another *possible* option—though I have no experience with this and thus cannot recommend it—is to merely normalize each batch. Any given batch needs to have the same length for all samples, but independent batches can have different lengths. Theoretically, you could partition your data based on sequence lengths, and then make batches with as little padding/truncating as possible. However, this could take a lot of effort, and might only work if sequence length is not correlated with anything else. I would recommend not attempting this approach.